# Checking if sum of arbitrary amount of cells in a column matches a cell in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, array

The result I would like to achieve is Column 'C':

[image]

To make this spreadsheet easier to copy/paste into your own, here is copy-pastable data:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Number
1000
300


800
300


200

ID
1
1
1
2
2
5
5
6
9
9
9
9

Number
100
300
700
200
100
600
300
300
900
100
100
300
```

I want to make it so that it can check if any of the combination of the numbers from each set of unique IDs sum up to the unique ID's number in Column 'A'. So for example, for ID 1, this is true because the '700' and '300' from Column 'E''s ID 1 is a possible set of numbers that sum up to the 1000 in Column B's ID 1. But for example for ID 5, there's no way to sum the given numbers '600' and '300' to get '800'.

I know I can use the `COUNT` function to count how many of each IDs there are in Column 'D', but because this can be any natural number including 0, I can't figure out a way to make an `IF`/`SUM` loop that ends when the count reaches either the min or max of the `COUNT` like you would in programming. Do I have to somehow create a sub-matrix of the IDs with their respective numbers and start the loop somehow?

I am not sure if I explained my thoughts clearly. Please ask for any clarification necessary. Thanks.

Comment: How many repeats of a given ID could there be in column D?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this with just worksheet formulae, you'll need to loop using VBA and even then it's going to scale up really fast to a lot of iterations as the number of numbers per id grows. For id `1` you have 7 combinations you have to consider but adding just one extra number like in id `9` means you have 15, that's exponential growth.

Comment: @Bandersnatch I guess I would limit it to 10

Comment: @user152294, check my edited post, now by using cumulative sum method I got the solution.

Comment: Nope, wrong again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you might have up to 10 ID numbers, and because the sum could be composed from **any** of the corresponding values in column E (including non-contiguous values), Dan is right:  you need a VBA solution.

This user defined function (UDF) owes a lot to this [answer from @Gary's Student](https://superuser.com/questions/1230158/making-a-list-of-po-combinations-that-equal-x-using-list-of-random-numbers/1230218#1230218):

```
Function CheckSums(ID, TargetSum)
    Dim NumBits As Long, NumSums As Long, RngStart As Integer
    Dim Mask As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim MaskArray() As Integer
    Dim SumArray() As Integer
    Dim TestSum As Long

    NumBits = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D:D"), ID)
    NumSums = 2 ^ NumBits - 1
    RngStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID, Range("D:D"), 0)

    ReDim MaskArray(NumSums - 1)
    ReDim SumArray(NumSums - 1)

    For i = 1 To NumSums
        Mask = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(i, NumBits)
        For j = 0 To NumBits - 1
            MaskArray(j) = Mid(Mask, j + 1, 1)
            If MaskArray(j) = 0 Then
                SumArray(j) = 0
            Else
                SumArray(j) = Range("E" & RngStart + j)
            End If
        Next j
        TestSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumArray())
        If TestSum = TargetSum Then
            CheckSums = True
            Exit Function
        End If
     Next i

    CheckSums = False
End Function
```

To use this function, paste it into a new VBA module as [described here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-a-macro-module-to-another-workbook-13c0938b-8432-4259-9177-a71f7e626de0).

Then this formula, filled down from C2:

`=IF(B2<>"",IF(CheckSums(A2,B2),"Yes",""),"")`

gives the results shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I've seen answers having VBA code where the keywords are and comments are in color.  Does anyone know how that happens? The Excel VBA editor shows colors, but as soon as you paste the code, it goes to b&w.

Comment: @ Bandersnatch, reason is simple, VB editor has also Colour Format scheme which is by default set to AUTO. If you want to change them. In editor windows click Tool, Option, you find Tab Page dialogue now hit Editor Format. You find Code colour, Font, Size and the Colour setting List boxes. Pick the element from Code colour like, 'Keyword Text' and apply Foreground, Background and Indicator colours.

Comment: In the Excel VBA editor, colors show correctly.  I was asking how to have colors in a SU answer.

Comment: @Bandersnatch I think it is a markdown implementation on here. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting This is what your answer would look like: https://i.imgur.com/35uIo2E.png

Comment: Hi, @user152294. That link was interesting, and [this linked reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) seems to indicate that the system can "infer" what language is being used and highlight the code accordingly.  I just copy/paste from the Excel VBA editor and usually get no color, like this answer, but sometimes get color, like in this [other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1307146/duplicating-excel-buttons-with-relative-reference/1307838?noredirect=1#comment1943590_1307838).  It's not at all obvious what the difference is.

Comment: @Bandersnatch I believe the system can automatically detect the language only if the appropriate tags are added in the post. So if I posted VBA in my original post and tagged my question with VBA, it would show the colors. But you can't do that in answers I think, so you'd have to manually add that line `<!-- language: lang-vba -->` to your answer

Comment: @Bandersnatch I just added the 'VBA' tag to my question. It looks like your answer has colors now

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED:**

It might be possible to solve this issue with a Cumulative Sum. So I've tried `SUMIF()` as shown below.  Also, note that I've used different data from that in the OP's question.

[image]

This formula in C2, gives the results shown.

```
=IF(B2<>"",IF(SUMIF($E$2:E2,E2,$B$2:B2)=B2,"Yes",""),"")
```

But note that the parameters for `SUMIF()` are specified as `SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)`.

As you can see, the above formula sums the values in Column B, not those in Column E, as specified in the question.  This formula finds and "sums" the target value in Column B and presents it as if it had calculated a legitimate answer.

Clearly, if you want a valid, intelligent answer to your question, you need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, in column B values are randomly written, If anyone use my formula with the same values, in C6 YES will appear which must not! I've used SUMIF for helper column in B and got 900 for B6 which is logically correct and in this case C6 has Blank. In rest of cells C2, C3, C7 and C10 my formula, in both cases produces YES (as the Screen Shot). Just test it. :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch, now I've fixed the issue using cumulative Sum method and it's  working properly.

Comment: Still it's matter to research, with 300, 100, 700 my formula is also working. I've tested it with around 15 overall combinations and only with 2, in C6 I got Yes. While change the location Your UDF produces #Value error or Yes in C6, even I've altered Range("D:D") to the new Range. Hope soon we crack it, have nice Sunday :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch, I'm always eager to learn,,, This data was used in recent past with a other question by the same user  then he replied me that it's randomly selected no logic so that I've had applied the SUMIF and you know ,,innovation always has many path and I must suggest you "appreciate ideas think beyond the box. Have nice time ,,soon I'll return now Out of country on assignment with client

Comment: If I put 400 for ID 10 then in next cell to it my Formula will also produce Yes ,if  ID 10 has values 200,500,500,200 that's Y i said Op's idea was Random numbers and so that I tried with SUMIF . **Yes, VBA can do it better like Gary's Student code did,** as your answer shows.