# Duplicating Excel buttons with relative reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am building an inventory workbook.  On each row is information related to a part number including count.  I wish to add a couple of buttons:

- One that will ADD one to the inventory count
- One that will SUBTRACT one from the inventory count

As a result, there will be two buttons controlling the inventory count on the same row.  I would like to be able to duplicate these buttons retaining relative reference in the workbook.  For example, the button copied/duplicated to Row 3 will control the inventory count for Row 3.

There will be 100's of rows and changing the control manually is not practical.  Ideally, the solution will create 1000 rows with the command buttons created.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds harsh, but what you're asking to do sounds like a very bad design for an inventory control system.  Inventory changes when sales or internal usage result in decreases and when purchases or manufacturing result in increases.  Inventory should be calculated and linked to those transactions, not a button click.  Any system you put into place should make it very difficult for inventory to be updated incorrectly.

Comment: Agreed.  This is for inventory carried in a van.  As a result there are probably less that 250 unique items of count less than 5.  The value of the approach is that it will be very easy for the users (technicians in a truck) to search for part availability and location, increase (receive parts) and decrease (use) parts.  Math in the spreadsheet with help with reordering decisions.

The reason for the spinner or macro connected button (vs. simply typing in a new total) is to make it very simple to change the count since adds to inventory and use are nearly always one at a time.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good idea to add Button to each row !! If you upload some of the rows from worksheet or upload to cloud, I will fix the issue.

Comment: One more question. How will users navigate to the row they want to update? Search for a part no, or name? Scroll manually? Also, what columns of information, text or numbers, are given foe each part?

Comment: On the primary sheet will be part number, part name*, vendor*, cost*, location, count (updated by buttons), total value (count x cost).  
Those with the * are brought in from a masterlist via a vlookup off the part number.  Search for part will be via Ctl+F or autofilters.

Comment: Adding to the explanation for this approach to the problem, the owner of our operating system is unable/unwilling to add this functionality thus this approach.  I want to keep it very simple as the users won't use it if it takes more than a few minutes to explain how to use.

Comment: So, maybe it could work like this:  users search or filter to find a part number.  The search would select the part number, triggering the buttons to move (see answer below).  Not sure about the filter, they'd probably have to select something to move the buttons.  Then clicking the buttons would add or subtract 1 from the count in the row that was selected.  Are the part numbers in column A, and count in column F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea.  How about creating only 2 buttons (instead of hundreds) and have them move to follow the selection?

EDIT: After some discussion and clarification, OP Phil asked for the inventory update buttons to appear adjacent to the selected cell when the user clicks in column F, and be hidden otherwise.

The video below shows the operation of the tagalong buttons:

[image]

The Worksheet has a simple macro that displays and moves the buttons:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = True
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 2).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2")
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 3).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
        End With
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = False
    End If    
End Sub
```

I couldn't change the color of regular Excel command buttons, so I inserted pictures, and assigned macros to the picture objects.  That's why they're referenced as Shapes("Picture 1") in the code above.  If you use normal Excel command buttons, the reference would change to the name of the button.

The buttons themselves have even simpler code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - 1
End Sub
```

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: Cool.  How about this? If the count cell is selected (always in Column J) this would trigger to show or activate the buttons to add/subtract.  So after the technician finds the part ( in # row), he clicks in the Inventory count cell (J#), and the buttons become active to update the count.  (I have no idea how complex that is.)

Comment: That should'nt be too hard at all.  Later.

Comment: Thanks Bandersnatch.  Nice simple code and easy to modify for the specifics of my worksheet.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: You're very welcome.  I think this is a pretty neat solution.  Sure beats copying hundreds of buttons.  :-)  Thanks for your feedback and consultations.