# MS Excel 2010 Tagalong Buttons

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm unable to get this code to work.

```
  If Target.Column = 6 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = True
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = True
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 2).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2")
            .Left = Target.Offset(, 3).Left
            .Top = Target.Offset(0).Top
        End With
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Visible = False
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Visible = False
    End If    
End Sub
```

This was available on [Duplicating Excel buttons with relative reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1307146/duplicating-excel-buttons-with-relative-reference) so instead of reviving an old thread, im posting here.

I have to use this to increase values on excel by 1, 0.1 and 0.01. Its impossible to create 300+ spin buttons. Any help will be really appreciated. Im a very basic Excel user.

[image]

Comment: Some information about the spreadsheet would help.

Comment: So would knowing what happens when you try to run the code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzNbi.png

Please check the image. 

Just for better understanding. These buttons will be used for changing the values of expense included in the price of an item to increase or decrease the price. Currently I have to type about 30 times to get desired results.

Comment: @ShahidMahmood,, since your sheet doesn't have button like object so that you are getting an error,, check the code below have code for buttons also !!

Comment: in the question you've referenced `Target` is passed to the sub as an argument. In your code `Target` isn't defined. What do you exactly want your code to do?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ncyg8k5

@MátéJuhász 
Please check the attached image. 
1) When i click any cell in price column (c7) these 8 buttons should pop up. 
2) They will do as the buttons say. Increase/decrease the values.