# Buttons in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, popups

In respect of previous questions asked here. [MS Excel 2010 Tagalong Buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/1466103/ms-excel-2010-tagalong-buttons)

I want these pop-up buttons, they should appear when they clicked on the cell and they should do what they are saying. I`m a very basic user so do not have much idea about making such buttons

[image: Buttons]]

Comment: Hello, may this link help you: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283

Comment: Hello, I have tried this, I can make the buttons but don`t know what code will be required to make the buttons work.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution?

Comment: unfortunately no. Still sticking to doing everything manually.