# Fill only empty cells in a table column with incremental values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have say a column A in a table which have some emty cells like following :

```
AB345  
AC545

XY675  

VY987  


AC879
```

I want to to fill the empty cells with unique values by taking an expression and incrementing it all over the empty cells, in a result like :

```
AB345    
XX1
AC545
XX2  
XY675  
XX3  
VY987  
XX4
XX5  
AC879
```

I have tried selecting the empty cells from the table column header, but when I drag the mouse from the first empty cell, it will also overwrite the non empty ones with the incremental values.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

For **A1** through **A100** try this short macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A100").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = "XX" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Adjust the 100 to suit your needs.  Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Gary's, sorry to be off topic, but I'm trying to find an answer that you (I think) posted a while back.  All I remember is that it used a binary number, and it struck me as brilliant as many of yours do.  :-). The binary number was used somehow as a mask, or as an index to select all combinations from a list, or...?  That's about all I remember. Does that ring any bells?

Comment: @Bandersnatch  I will search..................

Comment: I found it.  [Great answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1230158/making-a-list-of-po-combinations-that-equal-x-using-list-of-random-numbers/1230218#1230218).